# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0 - Android Studio

Tags: java, android

Делаю приложение под андроид и у меня появилась странная ошибка, хотя её не было в приложении с похожим кодом.

Ошибка:

```
    Process: com.kvaksmanyt.smartwatchnotifications, PID: 21709
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:338)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5494)
        at com.kvaksmanyt.smartwatchnotifications.AnecdotesActivity$1$1$1.getView(AnecdotesActivity.java:134)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2372)
        at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1408)
        at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1315)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22002)
        at android.widget.TableRow.measureChildBeforeLayout(TableRow.java:222)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1167)
        at android.widget.TableRow.onMeasure(TableRow.java:113)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22002)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
        at android.widget.TableLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(TableLayout.java:462)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:806)
        at android.widget.TableLayout.measureVertical(TableLayout.java:474)
        at android.widget.TableLayout.onMeasure(TableLayout.java:437)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22002)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$Measurer.measure(ConstraintLayout.java:792)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.measure(BasicMeasure.java:480)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.measureChildren(BasicMeasure.java:134)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.solverMeasure(BasicMeasure.java:277)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.measure(ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:119)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.resolveSystem(ConstraintLayout.java:1578)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1690)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22002)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:146)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22002)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:490)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22002)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22002)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:806)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:685)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22002)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:721)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22002)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2410)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1498)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1751)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1386)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6733)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
2020-12-08 22:02:13.141 21709-21709/com.kvaksmanyt.smartwatchnotifications E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Код адаптера:

```
ArrayAdapter<Anecdote> arrayAdapter =
  new ArrayAdapter<Anecdote>(getApplicationContext(), 0, anecdotes_list) {
      @Override
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
          if(convertView == null) {
              convertView = getLayoutInflater()
                      .inflate(R.layout.listadapter_anecdotes, null, false);
          }

          Anecdote currentAnecdote = anecdotes_list.get(position);

          ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.titleTV)).
                  setText(currentAnecdote.title);

          ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.anecdoteTV)).
                  setText(currentAnecdote.anecdote);

          ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.idTV)).
                  setText(position);

          return convertView;
      }
  };
```

Код listadapter_anecdotes:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleTV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/idTV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:text="ID"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/anecdoteTV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="3"
        android:text="Anecdote"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
</GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка из-за того, что есть метод TextView#setText, принимающий число, которое является ID строкового ресурса. Именно этот метод вы вызываете, а ID нужного нет.

> setText(position)

Чтобы отобразить число в TextView - делайте так:

```
setText(""+position)
```